# segmentation fault issue with string

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, arrays

I am trying to make a simple chat program and I am getting a segmentation fault, which to
my understanding is similar to a null pointer in java. I think I have located the problem but 
I have no clue how to fix it. It throws the error when trying to print the iP address.
How do I properly I have tried initializing it to this string? I have tried

```
char iP[20] = "asskdf";
```

and

```
char *iP;
strcpy(iP, "lsdlfkj");
```

Here is the code for my main. serverMenu does nothing yet

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define CAP 15
int size = 0;

int serverMenu(int task, char *userid, char *ipA);
struct user{
    char username[20];
    char *ipAdress;
    unsigned short portNumber;
};
struct user chatroom[CAP];
int main(){
char username[20];
char *iP;
strcpy(iP, "aasdas");
unsigned short portNumber;
printf("Welcome to the chat room!\n");
printf("Please enter your username (up to 20 characters long):\n");
scanf("%s", username);


printf("Please enter your TCP port number\n");
scanf("%hu", &portNumber);
int choice = 1;
printf("\n%s\n", username);
printf("%hu\n", portNumber);
printf("%d\n", choice);
printf("%s", iP);
serverMenu(choice,username,iP)
}
```

by popular demand, the server menu. this is my entire file so far

```
int serverMenu(int task, char *username, char *ipA){
printf("Successfully logged on as");
if(task == 1){
    if(size != CAP){
        printf("Successfully logged on as");
        strcpy(chatroom[size].username, username);
        strcpy(chatroom[size].ipAdress, ipA);
        //chatroom[size].portNumber = pN;
        size++;
        printf("Successfully logged on as");
    }
    else{
        printf("Sorry, there are no available spots in the chat room\n");
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `up to 20 characters long` - no, up to 19 characters long.

Comment: I think you might want to look into your serverMenu function for th eproblem

Comment: it was a random integer i threw in there for the array. that is not the point and would not throw the error. and leather face, it doesn't reach the print statement for iP so it doesn't make it to serverMeny

Comment: which line is it segfaulting

Comment: Earlier you said " It throws the error when trying to print the iP address", now "it doesn't reach the print statement for iP". You're wrong about at least one of those, so consider the possibility that you have another mistaken assumption. Please show the `serverMenu()` code.

Comment: exactly. It prints the choice, and then when trying to print the iP address, it doesn't print it. Thus not making it past the printstatement to server menyu but her is the code

Comment: Works like a charm ([demo](http://ideone.com/wR7uv4)). Add `\n` to the last `printf` to force it to finish printing *before* entering `serverMenu(choice,username,iP)` (by the way, you are missing a semicolon there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem line:

```
    strcpy(chatroom[size].ipAdress, ipA);
```

You have not allocated memory for `chatroom[size].ipAdress` before that call.

Also, in your previous edit, you had

```
char iP[20];
strcpy(iP, "aasdas");
```

Now you have

```
char *iP;
strcpy(iP, "aasdas");
```

The second form is not right. You need to have allocated memory for `iP` before you can use `strcpy`.

Comment: so this was throwing the error. How would one allocate memory for this? I am new to C and from java

Comment: I initialize the struct above everything?

Comment: OHHHH I see the issue. I am setting *iPaddress but i did not give it a size.